# Robot Framework - Adding Timestamp value to some text

Tags: java, robotframework

I have a User ID text field in a form. I need to enter some text along with current timestamp value [`ex: "abc_23022014_061600"`] into "User ID" text field. I can do this in Java like below.

**In Java:**

```
"abc_"+new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss").format(new Date());
```

But, using Robot Framework how can we add this timestamp value to User ID text field? i.e., Any keyword or library for getting timestamp?

**Using Robot Framework:**

```
input text | userId | abc_ | ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the specific format you want, you can create a python or java keyword, or write your own robot keyword that builds it.  As @MarkHu points out, the `Get Time` keyword will get the time you need.  Unfortunately it can't return the time in an artibtrary format, you have to build it yourself.  Something like this:

```
${yr} | ${mth} | ${day} | ${hr} | ${min} | ${sec}= | Get Time | year month day hour min sec
${dtStr}= | Catenate | SEPARATOR= | ${day} | ${mth} | ${yr} | _ | ${hr} | ${min} | ${sec}
```

Incidentally, when I needed to do this, I got the time from a database, which allowed me to format it they way I wanted.  If you are using a JDBC-wrapping library, this option is can be handy, esepecially if the generated time is to be compared to something generated server-side.

Comment: Newer versions of RF has more flexible format options per https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Custom+timestamp

Answer (score 6):

Yes, try `${secs} = Get Time    epoch` which returns the familiar unix count of seconds after the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). The return value is always an integer.

Docs link: [Get Time](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.7.7#Get%20Time).